# capture input and send key events at the same time

Tags: x11, keyboard, input-method

I'm looking to create a simple input method program. Currently, I'm able to capture input from any window using passive key grabs ([thanks user dirkt!](/a/400761)).

Separately, I'm also able to send key presses using `XTestFakeKeyEvent()`.

The issue is that I can't put these two parts together. When emitting a fake key event, it is received by my program instead of the intended application that has focus. This occurs even though my program does not have a passive grab on the keycode emitted by the fake event. I suspect this is because I'm getting events from the root window, but if I don't do that, I don't think I can capture input from other windows.

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/keysym.h>
#include <X11/extensions/XTest.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    Display *display;
    Window   rootwindow;
    XEvent   event;

    display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    rootwindow = DefaultRootWindow(display);

    XSelectInput(display, rootwindow, KeyPressMask);    

    unsigned int modifiers[] = {
        0, 
        ShiftMask,
        LockMask, //capslock
        Mod2Mask, //numlock
        ShiftMask | LockMask,
        ShiftMask | Mod2Mask,
        LockMask | Mod2Mask,
        LockMask | Mod2Mask | ShiftMask,
    };

    int keys [] = {
        XKeysymToKeycode(display, XK_A),
        XKeysymToKeycode(display, XK_B),
        ...
        XKeysymToKeycode(display, XK_Z)
    };

    int l;
    int m;
    for(l = 0; l < sizeof(keys)/sizeof(int); l++){
        for(m = 0; m < sizeof(modifiers)/sizeof(unsigned int); m++){
            XGrabKey(display, keys[l], modifiers[m], rootwindow, False, GrabModeAsync, GrabModeAsync);
        }
    }

    int repeat = 0;

    while (1) {

        XNextEvent(display, &event);

        if (event.type == KeyPress && event.xkey.send_event == 0) {
            printf("KeyPress: keycode %u state %u send-event %d\n", event.xkey.keycode, event.xkey.state, event.xkey.send_event);
            fflush(stdout);

            if(repeat == 0){ //to avoid infinite loops
                repeat = 1;

                XTestFakeKeyEvent(display, XKeysymToKeycode(display, XK_7), 1, CurrentTime);
                XTestFakeKeyEvent(display, XKeysymToKeycode(display, XK_7), 0, CurrentTime);
            }

        }
    }

    XCloseDisplay(display);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You may want to have a look at how `xbindkeys` does it (and `xte`/`xdotool` which you'd typically use there to  send key events).